# How can I configure NewRelic to show me page paths?

Tags: .net, configuration, newrelic

I'm trying to configure NewRelic's agent to show me meaningful page names for each transaction.

We are using a custom made engine and see all our transactions as `/OL.Web.Core.Handlers.HttpHandler`.

Following the steps outlined in [the documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/net-custom-instrumentation) I could only get to change names to `/ProcessRequest` which is still useless.

How do I change configuration to see page request names?

Answer (score 0):

The naming for .Net transactions is not based on page name, instead it uses controller/action for the name.  One option that might help would be to use the [.Net API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/features/net-agent-api#methods) and the **SetTransactionName** method to change the name.

Comment: From what I got from the docs, you have a set of classes that allow you to detect the kind of request that's being done and name the transactions accordingly. The Controller/Action is not something that's specific to an MVC framework? I have apps that use WebForms and I can see the .aspx file name associated with the request...